# Update id's for many to many mapping django

Tags: python, django-models, manytomanyfield

I have two models with many to many mapping:

```
class Child_details(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
   gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
   dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
   images_history = models.ManyToManyField(Image_history, blank=True)

class Image_history(models.Model):
    image_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, choices=PAGE_TYPES)
    image_link = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

Now that, I have two different objects for Child_details: child_obj1 and child_obj2. Since child_obj2 is a duplicate of child_obj1, I wanted to delete that object and before doing that I have to refer all image_history of child_obj2 to child_obj1.
I tried doing:

```
for image in child_obj2.image_history.all():
    image.child_details_id=child_obj1.id
    #but, I can't do the above one because there is no child_details_id in image_history model
```

Django creates a third table with child_details_id, image_history_id.
I wanted to change child_details_id in the third table created by django for many to many mapping.
Is it correct doing that and If so how can I?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Basically what I've done is I iterated through child_obj2's images_history and made entries in child_obj1's image_history.

```
for child_image_history in child_obj2.images_history.all():
    image_history = Image_history(image_type=child_image_history.image_type, image_name=child_image_history.image_name)
    image_history.save()
    child_obj1.images_history.add(image_history)
    child_image_history.delete()
```

And deleted the previous entries of child_obj2 which is not required.